# Is there a possibility to run autocomplete for an inner mode in codemirror?

Tags: autocomplete, codemirror

I am running freemarker as the inner mode and html as the base mode similar to the mustache template mode. I want to enable the autocompleter for freemarker when it is in the freemarker inner mode. Is it possible to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you have an autcompletion function for freemarker register it with `CodeMirror.registerHelper("hint", "freemarker", function(editor) { ... })`, and the `show-hint` addon will call it whenever autocompletion is activated in that inner mode.

This assumes that your inner mode is called `"freemarker"` (as per its `defineMode` call), and that your outer mode has a working `innerMode` method.

Comment: Thanks again Marijn for your input.